# Blackberry app loads data from Internet on Simulator, but nothing loads on device

Tags: xml, blackberry

We have an application that uses XML to load data on 8900 BB device. Everything is running well on Simulator, all relevant data load. But on device we get a black page and nothing loads. Can anyone help us find the problem? Maybe that's because we don't sign the application ?

We managed to load data only after we set APN in device network settings. All native and downloaded apps worked before without any APN settings, why didn't our application load data without APN ?

Comment: using unsigned api resolves in error message, so probably its connection or application permissions. what kind of connection are you using? are you using BES?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the "answer" to this is "networking is difficult on the BlackBerry".  There are some pretty good resources out there to get you quickly up-to-speed, though.  Here is a great post on the developer forums all about making network connections and the various different ways to accomplish your task:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=29103&query.id=48702#M29103

Additionally, an accomplished BlackBerry developer has posted a very nice utility class that you might want to try using to bullet-proof your connections more:

http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/

Comment: Where did you get the idea that networking is diffucult on the blackberry? it's easy as hell :)

Comment: Haha, I got that idea being naive enough to think it was going to be easy with my first app.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is long closed but thought to drop this incase someone out there needs it someday. This issue really slowed down my development for hours so I deemed it fit to share. I will provide two methods that will help check the device and use the appropriate transport available. To use this methods, just call the getConnectionString method and append to the end of your url string and you are good to go.

```
//the method returns the connection string
public  String getConnectionString()
{        
    String connectionString = "";                

    if(DeviceInfo.isSimulator())
    {
        if(true)// toggle between true and false to enable simulator use mds
        {
        //  Log.i(TAG, "Device is a simulator and USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR is true");
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false";                 
        }
        else
        {
        //  Log.i(TAG, "Device is a simulator and USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR is false");
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }
    }                                        

    // Wifi is the preferred transmission method
    else if(WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
    {
   //   Log.i(TAG, "Device is connected via Wifi.");
        connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
    }

    // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)
    {
//      Log.i(TAG, "Carrier coverage.");

        String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if(carrierUid == null) 
        {
            // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS.  So use the carrier's TCP network
       //   Log.i(TAG, "No Uid");
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }
        else 
        {
            // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS request
        //  Log.i(TAG, "uid is: " + carrierUid);
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }
    }                

    // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS)
    {
 //     Log.i(TAG, "MDS coverage found");
        connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }

    // If there is no connection available abort to avoid bugging the user unnecssarily.
    else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
    {
//      Log.i(TAG, "There is no available connection.");
    }

    // In theory, all bases are covered so this shouldn't be reachable.
    else
    {
      //  Log.i(TAG, "no other options found, assuming device.");
        connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }        

    return connectionString;
}

/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS network
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network. This is called from getConnectionString() 
 */
private String getCarrierBIBSUid()
{
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;

    for(currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++)
    {
        if(records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp"))
        {
            if(records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0)
            {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }      
    return null;
}
```

Sample usage can be found below:

```
String url  = "specific url"+getConnectionString();
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open( url, Connector.READ, true );
```

This method is full proof and has been tested across multiple devices so I thought to put it in a concise format here.
Good luck